# Aligning different characters in a tabular environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have a 8 column table and I wish to align the 4th and 5th column by the "-" or "+" character.

A minimal example :

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cccccccY}
  \hline
L1 & L2 & L3 & L4 & L5 & L6 & L7 & L8 \\ 
  \hline
1871 & 1874 & 1874 & [0 - 10] & [10 - 20] & 1874 & 45 \% & N \\ 
1878 & 1878 & 1878 & [10 - 20] & [20 - 30] & 1878 & 20 \% & M \\ 
1879 & 1879 & 1880 & [+ 50] & [0 - 10] & 1878 & 20 \% & M \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

So for column 4 I need [0 - 10], [10 - 20] and [+ 50] to be aligned on -, -, +. Same principle for the 5th column where [10 - 20] and [20 - 30] are aligned together but not with [0 - 10].

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a column for those characters then? And please post a MWE with class, commands and packages necessary, like `array` which you seem to be using to define the `Y` column

Answer (score 6):

You can split the respective `c` columns into two columns, `r@{}l`, like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccr@{}lr@{}lccc}
  \toprule
 L1  &  L2  &  L3  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{L4}
                               & \multicolumn{2}{c}{L5}
                                           &  L6  &   L7   & L8\\ 
  \midrule
1871 & 1874 & 1874 &  [0--&10] & [10--&20] & 1874 & 45\,\% & N \\ 
1878 & 1878 & 1878 & [10--&20] & [20--&30] & 1878 & 20\,\% & M \\ 
1879 & 1879 & 1880 &  [{+}&50] &  [0--&10] & 1878 & 20\,\% & M \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As soon as the entries in a column vary in width, you should switch to `r` columns (for numbers) or `l` columns (for text); to center the headings, replace `L1` by `\multicolumn{1}{c}{L1}` etc.